# Создание большого текстового файла java

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! Я недавно начала учиться и у меня следующий вопрос. Хочу создать текстовый файл с большим количеством строк (для примера взяла произведение Булгакова). Как это сделать? Я пыталась добавить его таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    /**
     * Проверка и создание каталога
     */
    System.out.println("Check for dir.");
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Bulgakov");
    System.out.println("dir.exists: " + dir.exists());
    if (!dir.exists()){
        System.out.println("Create new dir: " + dir.mkdirs());
    }

    /**
     * Проверка и создание текстового файла
     */
    System.out.println("Create a new File");
    File text = new File(dir, "first chapter.txt");
    System.out.println("File.exists: " + text.exists());
    if (!text.exists())
        System.out.println("Create a new File: " + text.createNewFile());

    writeToTextFile();
}

private static void writeToTextFile(File txtFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(txtFile);
         pw.println("Тут должен быть текст.");
}
```

Понимаю, что это не правильно (в данном случае) скопировать весь текст (и нереально). Значит нужно как-то по-другому его записать. Думала сделать через копирование из другого файла, но тогда, как мне кажется, если этот код запустить на другом устройстве, файл будет пуст, тк исходника (с которого копируется текст) не будет. Прошу прощения, возможно за глупый вопрос, но я не смогла найти информацию на данный вопрос или чего-то не поняла. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен ресурс с текстом. Ресурс - это данные которы можн добавить к программе на java. [Подробности](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Comment: А Вам принципиально нужен полный текст произведения? или подойдет просто большой текстовый файл с большим количеством любых/случайных строк?

Comment: Впринципе, можно любой текст. Просто это часть задания. (по заданию мне надо посчитать колиечество запятых) с подсчетом, я думаю, у меня проблем не должно будет возникнуть. Просто именно с файлом проблема возникла. Думала, что можно добавить такст по-другому. Спасибо большое за помощь! Пойду разбираться =)